# help I need to root my android due to "no memory space" but dont want to loose anything

Tags: rooting

I want to root my andriod as it keeps saying my memory is low it wont let me download anything even tho there is memory there ?? Will rooting delete pictures apps music or contacts ?? If so is there a back up I could do on everything ?? Please neeed hellp

Answer (score 0):

Rooting your android device is completely safe as long as you follow the instructions correctly. Rooting won't free up internal memory by itself. It does enable you to remove any unwanted system level apps. You could then use applications like link2sd to free up additional space. Do a quick search about how to root your device model at xda-developers.com. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it now , been having trouble with my sony xperia it keeps telling me I have low memory wont let me download anything evwn tho I have memory xx

Comment: The new version ot play store has increased the minimum required space for app installation. What model of sony xperia do you have? Rooting xperia phones shouldn't be very hard.